# Convert float time to datetime or timestamp in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timestamp, python-datetime

I have the following dataframe:

[image: df]

The column `Time` is a string and I want to convert it either to timestamp or datetime formats. However, when I run `df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])`, I always get an error

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 08:53:30
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are getting the right column and values. Because running

```
time = pd.to_datetime("13:30:35.805")
```

Gives

```
Timestamp('2020-04-20 13:30:35.805000')
```

as output as expected. 
If you can't solve the problem with pandas directly you can always manually split the string in hours, minutes and seconds with

```
h, m, s = map(float, x.split(':'))
```

And use those values to create a timestamp